# REGEXP for sentence with at least 3 words

Tags: regex

The pattern I am searching for sentences with at least 3 words. What I am trying to do now is:

`REGEXP '^[A-Za-z0-9_]* [A-Za-z0-9_]* [A-Za-z0-9_]*'` However I am coming up with 1474 results and when I went into excel to double check the result with formulas I am coming up with 1893. Am I missing some pattern? Because excel is noticing this sentence `L'orfeo, Act 3 Sinfonia (Orchestra)` but REGEXP is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` means 0 or more; I think you mean `+` in this case. `+` stands for 1 or more. You could also try using the character class `\w` for readability, as `\w` is usually equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, your regular expression doesn’t include an apostrophe…

Try just anything that’s not a space:

```
^\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+
```

Answer (score 2):

Your character class doesn't include `'` and `,` and hence the regex fails to make that match. You need

```
^[\w',]+\s[\w',]+\s[\w',]+
```

`\w` includes `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. I've added `'` and `,` to make it `[\w',]`. If you have a lot such non-alphanumeric characters that can be part of your words; it's better to match on `\S` i.e. not a whitespace (space, newlines etc.)

```
^\S+(\s\S+){2,}
```

Notice, the use of `+` everywhere (instead of `*`) which matches the pattern on *one or more* occurrences (instead of *zero or more*).